# Mixing « y » and « en » in the sentence « elle y en connaît plus que moi »

Tags: pronoms

> Elle **en** connaît plus que moi sur le sujet.

I just used this sentence in conversation and wondered if I could drop the part « sur le sujet » and swap in «  y » instead. That is, if it is already obvious of what she has a better knowledge than I do.

> Elle **y en** connaît plus que moi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to drop "sur le sujet" you have to also drop **en** and change by **s'y**.

I don't have the actual rule in mind, but the **s'** refers to "sur le sujet".

> Elle **s'y** connaît plus que moi.

--

a little trick outside of your question.
In France people use mostly :

> Elle s'y connaît mieux(plus) que moi sur le sujet.

and

> Elle en sait plus que moi sur le sujet.

It's just that the other sentences (your first one and the correction of the second one) are not that used because they doesn't sound really good, but are still correct and heared time to time.

Comment: Hi. In the reflexive form "**s'y connaître**", you need to use "**en**" instead of "**sur**", correct? Like, "**s'y connaître en qqch**"? But can you say "**en le sujet**", as in "**elle s'y connaît plus/mieux en le sujet que moi**"? Merci.

Comment: I would still use "elle s'y connait plus sur le sujet que moi".  Putting "en" there does not make much sense to the sentence.

Comment: No you can't use "en le sujet", you can use s'y connaitre **en** with generic nouns like "en histoire", "en littérature", "en danse".when you put **le** before the noun then you have to use s'y connaitre **sur** like, "sur la danse",

Comment: @JulianColin So can you say "elle **s'y** connaît plus/mieux **sur** le sujet que moi"? Or is it more like "elle **se** connaît plus/mieux **sur** le sujet que moi"? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA saying "elle se connait" makes no sense here. it would mean she knows herself, so with no subject after that. You may say "elle se connait mieux que moi", which means she knows herself better than I do...

Comment: @Random Merci. So I take it you cannot mix "y" and "sur" in "s'y connaître mieux sur le sujet"?

Comment: @LUNA Indeed you can mix "s'y" and "sur" ^^